# Enabling dynamic sharding in hibernate search causes index creation on elastic search to fail

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I have a scenario in which indexing works perfectly fine in a simple hibernate-search Elasticsearch integration setup, but the same fails when sharding is enabled. On debugging I see that the json data generated by hibernate search with sharding enabled is incorrect. More details below:

```
@Entity
public class AT {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ARRM_IDE", nullable = false)
    private A arr;

    private Date dateType;

    (and other fields)
}

@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "C_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "S_ARRM_01")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "C_SEQUENCE")
    @Column(name = "IDE_ARR")
    private Long id;
}

SearchMapping mapping = new SearchMapping();
mapping.entity(AT.class).indexed()
        .property("dateType", ElementType.FIELD)
        .field()
        .store(Store.YES)
        .analyze(Analyze.NO)
        .property("arr", ElementType.FIELD)
        .indexEmbedded()
        .entity(A.class).indexed()
        .property("id", ElementType.FIELD).documentId().name("arrId")
        .field()
        .store(Store.YES)
        .analyze(Analyze.NO)
        ;
```

without sharding in place the schema mapping and the insert data are like this:

```
{"dynamic":"strict","properties":{"__HSearch_TenantId":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"arr":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"long","store":true,"index":"not_analyzed","boost":1.0}}},"dateType":{"type":"date","store":true,"index":"not_analyzed","boost":1.0}}}"

"{"dateType":"2016-06-22T00:53:19Z","arr":{"id":15302}}"
```

I added the following to enable sharding

```
<property name="hibernate.search.at.sharding_strategy" value="com....ATShardIdentifierProvider" />
```

with this the mapping is same as above and insert data is as follows:

```
"{"dateType":"2016-06-22T01:05:08Z","id":15402}"
```

and the indexing clearly then fails with:

```
Status: 400
Error message: {"root_cause":[{"type":"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception","reason":"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [id] within [AT] is not allowed"}],"type":"strict_dynamic_mapping_exception","reason":"mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [id] within [AT] is not allowed"}
Cluster name: null
Cluster status: 400
```

Not sure if this is a bug? or somehting wrong with my code.

Thanks very much for the help!
Priya

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Could you provide a self contained test case so that we can reproduce it easily? We provide test case templates here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates . You have one for Elasticsearch support in search/hibernate-search-elasticsearch. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Guillaume - I just created a pull request with the tescase, will be happy to work on the fix if it gets identified as a bug!!.

Comment: I think you can open a JIRA issue explaining your case and with your test case attached. I'm not sure we will support internal sharding for Elasticsearch as it's probably a better idea to use the built in sharding support of Elasticsearch. That being said, we have to either fix it or explicitly states that it is not a supported configuration and throw a proper error. Either way, we need an issue to track that! Thanks!